# How do I create a form which will save similar data across all tables?

Tags: ms-access

I know that you can save one form data to a specific table but I'm not sure how to do it for multiple tables. I've enforced referential integrity in my relationships but nothing happened.

Comment: Possibly you need to use form/subform arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you likely need to add a bit more information.

As a “general” rule, a form is bound to a table. It lets you edit, or add records to that table.

However, given that Access allows you to deal with relational data, then to save records to “more” than one table, those tables will follow the “relations” you setup between those tables.

So for example, if you have say an invoice form, then the top part of the “main” form could (would) be bound to the table “invoices”. And for each invoice, you have “detail” lines. That is a table (likely called table: InvoiceDetails).

So your result is a form like this:
[image]

So you never really make “one” form write to multiple tables, but you most certainly will build a form and add additional forms to that one form. These “additional” forms are what we call “sub forms” in Access.

The “base” concept here is that the form will “appear” to update multiple tables, but the form is in fact made up of MORE than one form. These additional “sub forms” are how you edit (and add) related data tables in Access.

In above, the top part (our main form) is bound to table “invoices”, and each line of invoice detail (table invoiceDetails) is a sub form below. And access forms can display one record, or “many” records. When you need to edit (or add) multiple records to a table, then you create a “multiple items” form (let the wizard create the form for you).

Each form is as a general rule “bound” to one table, but by cobbling together multiple forms into “one” form (as related sub forms), you achieve the goal of editing data in multiple tables.

So above is just really a regular plane jane Access form. However the "repeating" details part is another form (a sub form, and is a multiple items form).